# Can the Hexblood's token be used for rudimentary two-way communication?

Tags: dnd-5e, unearthed-arcana, racial-traits

In the recent [Gothic Lineage](https://media.wizards.com/2021/dnd/downloads/UA2021_GothicLineages.pdf) UA, the Hexblood race was introduced. One of their abilities is Magic Token:

> Magic Token. As an action, you can harmlessly pull out one of your nails, a tooth, or a lock of hair. This token is imbued with magic until you finish a long rest. While the token is imbued in this way, you can use an action to send a telepathic message to the creature holding or carrying the token, as long as you are on the same plane of existence and are within 10 miles of it. The message can contain up to twenty-five words.
>
> In addition, while you are within 10 miles of the token, you can use an action to enter a trance for 1 minute, during which you can see and hear from the token as if you were located where it is. While you are using your senses at the token’s location, you are blinded and deafened in regard to your own surroundings. Afterward, the token is harmlessly destroyed.

I want to ask if the following scenario is a viable use of this feature:

1. Hexblood character A creates a token and gives it to character B.
2. Later that day, A, as an action, sends a message to B. "Hey, in one minute, we do the thing."
3. Nine turns later, A uses his action to enter the trance, sending his awareness to the token, currently held by B.
4. B starts speaking and/or shows something to the token, through which A sees and hears.
5. A uses their subsequent nine actions to send rapid-fire twenty-five-word messages to B, who responds by speaking aloud. The trance renders you blind and deafened, but not incapacitated.

While not ideal, this sounds like it would, once a long rest, with considerable setup, allow for two-way communication. Is there a reason it wouldn't?

Answer (score 1):

Everything about your setup appears to work. Although the classical use of the token might be to spy on a target, as you mentioned nothing prevents communication working with a Telepathic one way and Vocal the other way communication.

Effectively it would be similar to if a creature spoke to you with telepathy and you chose to respond with your voice.